# Running cocoa application outside Xcode

Tags: xcode, cocoa

When I'm running my cocoa application inside Xcode it works fine. 
But I'm going to where the .app file is and run it from there this error shows up:

```
Process:         QBLoader [4571]
Path:            /Users/USER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QBLoader-egxdvwlbzueazygfdbjqcxtgyvqz/Build/Products/Debug/QBLoader.app/Contents/MacOS/QBLoader
Identifier:      com.fsm.QBLoader
Version:         1.0 (1)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [210]

Date/Time:       2012-05-25 09:25:31.121 +0200
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.3 (11D50)
Report Version:  9

Interval Since Last Report:          62057 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           10
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  20 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   10
Anonymous UUID:                      5DEC6815-69C3-48FA-A3C4-3EEBC31CC1B6

Crashed Thread:  0

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/SBJson.framework/Versions/A/SBJson
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QBLoader-egxdvwlbzueazygfdbjqcxtgyvqz/Build/Products/Debug/QBLoader.app/Contents/MacOS/QBLoader
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: It looks like you don't have `SBJson.framework` installed in an appropriate Frameworks directory.

Comment: Ok can you give me some more information? This is my build phases tab: http://i.imgur.com/fUsUl.png

Comment: You need to read up on deploying third party frameworks with your app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what worked for me.
I changed "Installation directory" for the SBJson target to: "@executable_path/../Frameworks".
Now is it possible to run the application outside Xcode.