# How to run objective-c console application (with a library) outside of xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a simple console application intended to exercise a library from a larger project.  The console application is one target within an XCode project that also contains the library ( plus some other targets I don't care about right now).  The console target references the  library by listing it in the Build Phases "Target Dependencies" and "Link Binary with Libraries".

I can run the console program just fine from within XCode by clicking the "Run" button and examining the console output under "All Output".

However I get a load error if I try to run outside of XCode.  I select the console application under "Products" in the project navigator, and then I locate the "Full Path" in the "Identity" section of the information panel.  When I copy this path to a terminal window and run it, I get an error like:

```
dyld: Library not loaded:
@executable_path/../Frameworks/[LIBRARY].framework/Versions/A/[LIBRARY]
Referenced from: [THE PATH THAT I TYPED]
Reason: image not found
```

What should I do differently to get my console application to execute from the console?

(Note, in the "Copy Files" phase, I have tried leaving the "Subpath" blank and setting it to "@executable_path/../Frameworks" per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10751627/4540), which was about a cocoa app, but neither way has helped.)

Comment: can you find the framework in the bundle? maybe you need a copy framework phase

Comment: @xlc -- alas I don't even know what that means.  I'm coming from a GCC/MSVC background, where you compile it and run it and only then consider attaching a debugger, so it's deeply strange to me that this runs in the environment but not outside it.  I will google your words tomorrow and see where they lead me!

Comment: it is missing dll problem in msvc world. find where is `executable_path`, and check is this file exists `executable_path/../Frameworks/[LIBRARY].framework/Versions/A/[LIBRARY]`

Comment: Your runtime search path needs to point to `@loader_path/.../<FRAMEWORK_DIR>` in order for the DYLD to load it on startup.

Answer (score 1):

As the commenters above explain, dyld is the dynamic loader and it is looking for my library at the path it printed.  (When it says `@executable_path`, it means the location of the console application I'm actually trying to run.)

Looking at the compiled output from XCode, I see a folder hierarchy like this:

```
Debug/
    MyProgram
    Frameworks/[LIBRARY].framework/Versions/A/[LIBRARY]
```

For whatever reason, this structure does not match what the loader wants -- it is looking for the library at `../Frameworks` rather than `./Frameworks`.

Rather than messing with the environment variables used by the loader or trying to tweak the program itself, I just copied these files a new folder with the structure specified in the error message:

```
foo/
    bin/MyProgram
    Frameworks/[LIBRARY].framework/Versions/A/[LIBRARY]
```

I can now run `foo/bin/MyProgram` from the terminal without any problem.