# Loading Dynamic Libraries on Outisde Computers

Tags: xcode, cocoa, dynamic-library

so I built my project and it runs just fine on my own computer, but it does not run on others's. The reason is because I am using the GMP library which is not on their system, so I am wondering how do I fix that?

The console spit this error message out:

---

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/Downloads/NSnAy.app/Contents/MacOS/NSnAy.temp_caseinsensitive_rename
  Reason: image not found

---

I made [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109085/adding-frameworks-to-project-in-xcode-5-and-having-relative-paths-added) change, which didn't change anything. I also saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750381/running-cocoa-application-outside-xcode), but it didn't really help me either. I also included the .dylib file in the bundle resources, so maybe if I could somehow set the access link to the content package of the app it might work? But I don't know how, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though you've missed a critical step: adding a Copy Files build phase in your target's build phases, set to copy your local copy of the library into the application bundle *as a library* (not a resource, which will end up in the Resources subfolder of the app bundle).

[This question/answer may help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102609/build-cocoa-application-bundle-with-private-dylib-framework)

[This post by Mike Ash](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-11-06-linking-and-install-names.html) is also helpful though you've indicated you've already set the @executable_path (worth double-checking to verify it's set that way for your release build too though).